# how to edit json file in swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I have an array of arrays called "clubRanking" and a json file called "data.json". I changed the array of arrays to a json format with the code

```
func arraytojson(){
    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: clubRanking, options: [])
        if let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(dataString)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

After changing it to a json format I have

```
[
   {"nickname":"Liverpool","Pts":21, "Pos":1},
   {"nickname":"Spurs","Pts":21, "Pos":2},
   {"nickname":"Chelsea","Pts":19, "Pos":3}
]
```

This is the json file "data.json" with the following data

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
        "nickname": "Spurs",
        "code":"TOT",
        "Pos":1,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Liverpool F.C.",
        "nickname": "Liverpool",
        "code":"LIV",
        "Pos":1,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Chelsea",
        "code": "CHE",
        "nickname":"Chelsea",
        "Pos":1
    }
]
```

Now I want to update the json file with the json data I have with matching nicknames. So each json file data with matching nicknames gets updated.

Comment: Decode your data.json and match the struct(s) with `clubRanking`. You should solve this using swift types and not by working directly with json data.

Comment: You have tagged `arrayofarrays` but we are clear that's an array of dictionaries at most, right ;)